# something unexpected in python when i design a nested list

Tags: python-3.x

i want to turn 'a' to a nested list:
so i design a while loop:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
ll = l = []
m,f,k = 1,0,4

while m <= 3:

    l.append(a[int(f):int(k)])
    f = f + 4
    k = k + 4

    ll.append(l)
    m = m+1

print(ll)
```

i want `[[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12]]` rather than`[[1, 2, 3, 4], [...], [5, 6, 7, 8], [...], [9, 10, 11, 12], [...]]`

why the result contains `[...]` 
where is the problem in while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are mutable objects, so `ll=l=[]` means that `ll` is the
*exact same* object as `l`. This can be verified using the `is` operator:

```
>>> ll is l
True
```

This can be demonstrated as follows:

```
>>> a=b=[]
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[]
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>> b # For all practical purposes, a is identical to b
[1]
>>> a is b
True
```

Therefore, the line `ll.append(l)` **creates a recursive object!**
Using the `pprint` module after running the above code states this clearly:

```
>>> # Run the posted code
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(ll)
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 <Recursion on list with id=2032187430600>,
 [5, 6, 7, 8],
 <Recursion on list with id=2032187430600>,
 [9, 10, 11, 12],
 <Recursion on list with id=2032187430600>]
```

The `ll` list isn't actually necessary, since the `l.append` method already
appends the newly generated list to the `l` object and creates a 2D list:

```
>>> q=[[1,2,3,4]]
>>> q.append([5,6,7,8])
>>> q
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

The code can be rewritten as follows:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
l = list()
f,k = 0,4

# range(1,4) iterates m through the values [1, 2, 3]
# This includes the first but excludes the last
for m in range(1,4):

    # f and k are already integers, so no need for typecasting
    # This append statement will append the 1D slice as a single unit
    l.append(a[f:k])
    # a += 1 is the same as a = a + 1 but is more compact
    f += 4
    k += 4

print(l)
# Will be [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

If you really need to create two separate empty lists, it is better to do it this way:

```
>>> q=list()
>>> w=list()
>>> q is w
False
```